# mysqli_connect() causes fatal error - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I have the following lines of code in a script;

```
include '../details.php';
$conn = false;
//$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $serverpassword, $dbname);
if(!$conn){
    echo "no connection";
    //header("location: //www.mattwoolford.co.uk/contact/?err=003");
}
```

The commenting out and `$conn = false;` is for debugging, as is the `echo` statement. Here's the deal:

When I uncomment `$conn = mysqli_connect()`, the page goes blank from an error. Tried `or die()` to no avail. Tested echoing the credentials from details.php, and they present themselves correctly and successfully.

What's happening and why?

### UPDATE:

Error is shown to occur on a following line:

```
$service = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $service);
```

"Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in ("path") on line 81"

### UPDATE 2:  FIXED

An `EOT;` was indented, so it was trying to convert all the functions respectively as if it were included within `<<<EOT
EOT;`

Comment: Check your error logs or enable displaying of errors on screen (don't do this if it's public).

Comment: Seems there is no error.

Comment: @naththedeveloper Thanks for your reply, the fatal error is: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /var/www/mattwoolford.co.uk/public_html/booking/process-booking.php on line 81". This is a mysqli_real_escape_string() line. But there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with this either? - $service = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $service);

Comment: post that code which causes the error

Comment: What do you have later on in your code? That snippet won't generate that error

Comment: Just edited. The error occurs on: $service = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $service);

Comment: @Exprator $service is a string. Equivalent to a name of a product product except a service like "photography"

Comment: @Exprator "graphic%20design" is the value in this sense (and decoded "graphic design")

Comment: The error occurs even when I comment out that line, and it still refers to line 81

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple things happen:

1. Confirm the file path, may be it's not getting the actual file path.
2. Try to connect with mysql connection setting, May server support earlier mysql version.
3. Final thing, check for the dbname, username, password and host url.

So there can be only these three possibility, Try to do it.

It should fix.

Thanks

Comment: Did do this, all okay. Question edited to show where the script fails. I host two sites on this server, and they should both support mysqli. :/